# TextMate with python... not loading all imports ... why?

Tags: python, import, textmate

I just downloaded TextEdit to develop Python scripts.  It looks really nice, and the basics work great.

However, it is very hit or miss with using import statements.

These work:

```
import time
import turtle
```

These dont:

```
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *
```

For the two above, I get this message:

> 'No module named ...'

Can someone tell me how to fix this?  I don't know why some imports work and some don't.  The ones that don't work I typed straight out of a recent, high-quality textbook, so I don't know why they don't work.

Thank you.

Comment: `tkinter` may not be installed with all Pythons, and `urllib.request` isn't a module.

Comment: Check your Python version. In Python 2, `tkinter` is `Tkinter` and there is no `urllib.request` in Python 2 either like there is in Python 3. This is what could be causing your `ImportError`.

Comment: Why there is no urllib.request? It imports in my machine perfectly!